# Date Time Conversion: Number to Date Time

Tags: matlab

I have date & time in intervals of **one hour(3600 seconds) in number format, e.g 0,3600, 7200, 10800, 14400, 18000 etc.**
I have starting date and time , **e.g 0 corresponds to 2005/06/01 01:00 in 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM' format.**

I am writing this data to Excel file, so I am looking for way where I can convert time given in Hour (in seconds) to **Date Time (2005/06/01 01:00, 2005/06/01 02:00 etc)** before writing to excel file.

I have explored 'datenum' and 'datestr' functions but they are not useful since I can not give them customised start time i.e (0 corresponds to 2005/06/01 01:00).
May be if some one can help me to point me in right direction.

```
tempMatrix = [NrID time_inSec ff X Y];
tempMatrix_dataCell=num2cell(tempMatrix);
col_header={'NrID','Time','ff','X','Y'};
data_for_xls_file=[col_header; tempMatrix_dataCell];
xlswrite('My_file.xls',data_for_xls_file);
```

time_inSec is column with values 0, 3600, 7200, 10800 etc which need to be converted.

When I use **datenum** it returns 7.3246e+05 so when I add 3600 to get 2005/06/01 02:00 and pass it to **datestr** it returns 2015/04/10 01:00.

```
 temp_time = datenum('2005/06/01 01:00','yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM')
```

Comment: The mentioned functions `datenum` and `datestr` are useful and you can use them to do what you want. Please provide some code (minimal required) to reproduce your problem.

Comment: `datenum` makes a number that is in units of days. Just convert your "hours" from their units of seconds to days and add them to the `datenum` of you dates. Then convert them to Excel date numbers using [`m2xdate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/m2xdate.html)

Comment: @Dan Thanks, I was working in diff units

Answer (score 0):

This works with a given start time:

```
startTime = datenum('2005/06/01 01:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM'); % Define start time.
currentTime = datenum('2005/06/01 02:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM'); % Current time.
timePassedHours = (currentTime - startTime) * 24; % Time that has passed in hours.
display(timePassedHours); % Print the output.
```